# nat rules in /etc/ufw/before.rules not applied on reboot

Tags: networking, ufw

I followed the guide [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html#ip-masquerading) to add some rules to the `nat` table. Everything worked fine until I decide to reboot the server to see if everything works. Well, it doesn't. After reboot, `PREROUTING` section in `nat` table is empty (I checked with `iptables -t nat -L`).

If I run `ufw reload` or `ufw disable & ufw enable` and check again, the rules are added just fine. I tried to reset ufw (`ufw reset`) and start from scratch, no good - once I reboot, `PREROUTING` section would contain nothing.

I see guides about how to apply the rules without reboot, but I want the rules to **persist between reboots**. What am I missing?

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-F
-A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 587 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9587
COMMIT

(I didn't touch anything below, I added -F so I don't get duplicate rules during ufw reloads)

#
# rules.before
#
# Rules that should be run before the ufw command line added rules. Custom
# rules should be added to one of these chains:
...
```

(Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, ufw 0.35)

---

Some updates: I've tried all kinds of resetting, nothing helps, so I just gave up. I went back to old-school iptables and use `iptables-persistent` to restore my iptables on reboot. If anyone get any idea how can I make ufw work, please do let me know.

Comment: Same issue.  I ended up adding the rule to `/etc/rc.local` as per the next section in the doc you referenced.

Comment: Same issue.  Also Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with ufw 0.35.

Comment: In a few bug reports that i read, the ufw team emphasizes that ufw does not manage in any way the PREROUTING or the POSTROUTING chains.  and in the comments on `rules.before` it mentions 

     Custom
     # rules should be added to one of these chains:
     #   ufw-before-input
     #   ufw-before-output
     #   ufw-before-forward

Not sure what that means exactly since you mention that disabling and reenabling ufw seems to add the rules just fine.